# Playing sounds in sequence with SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: ios, audio, simpleaudioengine

I'm building an iOS app with cocos2d 2, and I'm using SimpleAudioEngine to play some effects.

Is there a way to sequence multiple sounds to be played after the previous sound is complete?

For example in my code:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"yay.wav"];
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"youDidIt.wav"];
```

When this code is run, `yay.wav` and `youDidIt.wav` play at the exact same time, over each other.

I want `yay.wav` to play and once complete, `youDidIt.wav` to play.

If not with SimpleAudioEngine, is there a way with AudioToolbox, or something else?

Thank you!

== **UPDATE** ==

I think I'm going to go with this method using AVFoundation:

```
AVPlayerItem *sound1 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yay" ofType:@"wav"]]];
AVPlayerItem *sound2 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YouDidIt" ofType:@"wav"]]];    
AVQueuePlayer *player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sound1, sound2,  nil]];
[player play];
```

Comment: Edited: found a method that is currently working.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be getting the track duration using `-[CDSoundSource durationInSeconds]` and then schedule the second effect playing after a proper delay:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] performSelector:@selector(playEffect:) withObject:@"youDidIt.wav" afterDelay:duration];
```

An easier way to get the audio duration would be patching SimpleAudioManager and add a method that queries its `CDSoundEngine` (a static global) for the audio duration:

```
- (float)soundDuration {
    return [_engine bufferDurationInSeconds:_soundId];
}
```

The second approach would be polling on the status of the audio engine and wait for it to stop playing.

```
    alGetSourcei(sourceId, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
    if (state == AL_PLAYING) {
      ...
```

The `sourceId` is the `ALuint` returned by `playEffect`.

Comment: Can you really get a durationInSeconds from a ALuint sound?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, tested with Cocos2D 2.1:

1. Creates a property durationInSeconds on SimpleAudioEngine.h :

   ```
   @property (readonly) float durationInSeconds;
   ```
2. Synthesize them :

   ```
   @synthesize durationInSeconds;
   ```
3. Modify playEffect like this :

   ```
   -(ALuint) playEffect:(NSString*) filePath pitch:(Float32) pitch pan:(Float32) pan gain:(Float32) gain {
       int soundId = [bufferManager bufferForFile:filePath create:YES];
       if (soundId != kCDNoBuffer) {
           durationInSeconds = [soundEngine bufferDurationInSeconds:soundId];
           return [soundEngine playSound:soundId sourceGroupId:0 pitch:pitch pan:pan gain:gain loop:false];
       } else {
           return CD_MUTE;
       }
   }
   ```
4. As you can see, I inserted durationInSeconds value directly from soundEngine bufferDurationInSeconds from the result of bufferManager.
5. Now, only ask for the value [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].durationInSeconds and you've got the float duration in seconds of this sound.
6. Put a timer this seconds and after this, play the next iteration of your sound or put the flag OFF or something.